# What is the purpose of actual keyword in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I noticed that some functions for coroutines are marked with `actual` keyword.

From [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html):

> actual denotes a platform-specific implementation in multiplatform
>   projects

As I understood from [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) `actual` keyword is used for multiplatform projects and should work in pair with `expect` keyword.

Something like this:

Common module:

```
package org.jetbrains.foo

expect class Foo(bar: String) {
    fun frob()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Foo("Hello").frob()
}
```

Corresponding module:

```
package org.jetbrains.foo

actual class Foo actual constructor(val bar: String) {
    actual fun frob() {
        println("Frobbing the $bar")
    }
}
```

That case is clear.

But in package `kotlinx.coroutines.experimental` I noticed that some functions like `launch` or `withContext` are marked as `actual` but there are no `expect` functions in package.

So what is the purpose of `actual` keyword **without** `expect`?

Comment: `actual` denotes a platform-specific implementation in multiplatform projects - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#modifier-keywords

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The kotlinx.coroutines library actually makes use of multiplatform projects since it supports both the JVM and JS compilation targets.

You can find the common module [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common), and the specific `expect` declarations for the functions you've mentioned [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/Builders.common.kt).

Comment: Well so that works only with expect/actual pair. Thank you!

Comment: I found more information on `expect` and `actual` use in multiplatform implementations at this link: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html#platform-specific-declarations

Comment: I am not able to find `expect` declarations in the second link.

Answer (score 7):

While the source code in the other answer helped, I found [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-connect-to-apis.html) (linked off of the page @jim-andreas mentioned in the comments above) was much more helpful.

Specifically, this passage:

> If you're developing a multiplatform application that needs to access platform-specific APIs that implement the required functionality (for example, generating a UUID), use the Kotlin mechanism of *expected* and *actual declarations*.
>
> With this mechanism, a common source set defines an *expected
> declaration*, and platform source sets must provide the *actual
> declaration* that corresponds to the expected declaration. This works
> for most Kotlin declarations, such as functions, classes, interfaces,
> enumerations, properties, and annotations.
>
> [image]
>
> The compiler ensures that every declaration marked with the `expect` keyword in the common module has the corresponding declarations marked with the `actual` keyword in all platform modules. The IDE provides tools that help you create the missing actual declarations.

Again, for more information, you can visit [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-connect-to-apis.html).